# rxLocationManager looping

Tags: android, rx-java2, subject

I've made a LocationManager to handle permission issues and return lastLocation from FusedLocationProviderClient. It uses RxJava heavily to avoid callback hell. Here's the code:

```
object LocationManager {

    // using coarse location to not ask for GPS enabling
    // after changing to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION don't forget to check GPS settings
    private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

    private var permissionSubject = AsyncSubject.create<Boolean>()

    fun loadLastLocation(activity: Activity): Observable<Location?> =
            checkPermission(activity).flatMap { hasPermission ->
                // check permission, then request last location
                Log.d("qwerty", "hasPermission=$hasPermission")
                if (hasPermission) requestLastLocation(activity)
                else Observable.error<Location>(Exception("Permission not granted"))
            }

    private fun checkPermission(activity: Activity): Observable<Boolean> =
            if (activity.hasPermission(LOCATION_PERMISSION)) Observable.just(true)
            else requestPermission(activity)

    private fun requestPermission(activity: Activity): Observable<Boolean> = permissionSubject.apply {
        // result will be posted to subject later
        Log.d("qwerty", "requestPermission $LOCATION_PERMISSION")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(LOCATION_PERMISSION), RequestCode.LOCATION_PERMISSION)
    }

    // call this from hosting activity or you can never get lastLocation
    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == RequestCode.LOCATION_PERMISSION) {
            permissionSubject.apply {
                val granted = grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                Log.d("qwerty", "onRequestPermissionsResult=$granted")
                onNext(granted)
                onComplete()
            }
        }
        // skip other request codes
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    // check ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION before calling this
    private fun requestLastLocation(activity: Activity): Observable<Location?> = PublishSubject.create<Location>().apply {
        Log.d("qwerty", "requestLastLocation")
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity).lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                    Log.d("qwerty", "lastLocation=$location")
                    onNext(location)
                    onComplete()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { error ->
                    Log.d("qwerty", "lastLocation error: ${error.message}")
                    onError(error)
                }
    }
}
```

And fragment calls LocationManager like this:

```
    LocationManager.loadLastLocation(activity!!)
            .subscribe(
                    { location -> Log.d("qwerty", "fragment got location $location")},
                    { error -> error.printStackTrace() }
            )
```

The problem is Observable stucks in infinite loop trying to get permission. Here's what I get in logs, infinite times:

```
qwerty: requestPermission android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
qwerty: hasPermission=false
System.err: java.lang.Exception: Permission not granted...
qwerty: onRequestPermissionsResult=false
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Is `LocationManager.loadLastLocation(activity!!)` being executed in `onResume()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can see from this code, it should work properly. Please check in your manifest that it  tag contain the same permission that you are requesting. And second one, please check in you Location manager imports, that proper Manifest class is imported (`android.Manifest` not `your.app.package.Manifest`).

Comment: yep, I had ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in Manifest. Thanks!